# How to dynamic serialize parameter in flink streaming

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a parameter `params` to serialize in flink streaming,

```
class P extend Serializable {...}

val params = new P(...)
val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
env.addSource(new MySource(params))
   .map(new MyMap(params))
   .addSink(new MySink(params))
env.setParallelism(1)
env.execute("My Job")
```

But params would change in driver node and I need to update `params` to executor during job running. Is it possible based on no stop of flink streaming job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in short, the answer is no. Because your UDF will need to [de]serialize the parameters every time a new record comes and this will slow down the execution.

However, you can implement your own stream operator by extending [AbstractUdfStreamOperator](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/operators/AbstractUdfStreamOperator.html) and call it in a [transform operation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/datastream/DataStream.html#transform-java.lang.String-org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation-org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.OneInputStreamOperator-) . I did one example here: "[Implementing my own stream operator in Flink to deal with data skew](http://felipeogutierrez.blogspot.com/2019/04/implementing-my-own-stream-operator-in.html)".

Then you decide on the operator when to read the new parameter. Just create a new thread that is schedule to every 10 minutes for instance. The parameter files have to be placed on all nodes that the operator will be running.